# Do I need a separate app for AndroidWear

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

My app has a "mobile" module and a "wear" module in AndroidStudio with a goal of producing a native version of the app for Android wear and for the phone. So when generating the apk through Android studio, 2 apk's are produced. Does this mean on the Google Play Developer console I need 2 separate app listings? Which means I would also need separate packages for the apps(since no 2 can be the same)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Wear generate two apk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599852/android-wear-generate-two-apk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Google Play store, the small `wear` application needs to be packaged inside the larger `mobile` application following these [gradle instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html), or these [manual instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually).

For debugging purposes, you'll need to update and debug both applications separately. That is why Android Studio initially sets them up that way.

Comment: So which apk should I use?

Comment: Wait, I'm going to look at the developer console.

Comment: OK thank you. To be more clear: The apk generator creates "wear-release.apk" and "mobile-release.apk" at the same time. Which one should I upload to the developer console?

Comment: As has been said before: when creating the release build, a properly set up Gradle build file will compile an APK for the wearable and copy this to the _/assets_ folder of the mobile APK. You should then upload _mobile-release.apk_ to the Play store using the developer console. When the user installs your app on their mobile device and Android detects a connected wearable device, the wear APK will automatically be transferred to the wearable device.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Android studio will generate two apks, named mobile-release.apk and wear-release.apk.

But you need to upload mobile-release.apk into play store. this apk is already bundled along with the wear apk.