# Should an android wear app self-install from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bluetooth, wear-os

I have developed an android wear app and corresponding mobile app (as per https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) using Eclipse.  My cell phone and wearable (Zen watch) are of paired over Bluetooth and working fine.  I attach my cell phone to my development PC via USB (with debug on).  By running my cell phone app from Eclipse, selecting the hardwired cell phone as the target device, should the wearable app install on the wearable device (assuming I packaged it correctly)?

Answer (score 1):

Wear apps will not install automatically with the mobile/handheld installation when signing apps with a debug key while developing.  So when you build, you are signing with a debug key.  See the "Note" at the top of the page you reference in your question (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html).

You have two options to install to the Wearable

1. You can install directly to the Wear unit by debugging over Bluetooth. This article does a good job explaining how to do this https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html
2. You can sign your app as if you were ready to release it and then install to your mobile handheld  using "adb install my-mobile-app.apk"

Of course #2 only works given you've followed the rules at the link you mention above - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html.

Comment: Thank you @Fat Russell.  I should have read the Note at the link closer.  I tried signing the app during the export from Eclipse then using adb as you suggest in #2.  Again, I must not be following the directions precisely because using adb to install over the USB, the cell app installed on the cell phone, but the embedded wearable app did not install on the wearable device.  I think I might change IDE from Eclipse to Studio.

Comment: MikeR  - This might not be your exact situation, but check out this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004530/android-wear-app-not-installing-through-handset   Its a little old but still has some relevant information.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I converted from Eclipse to Android Studio, and the wearable app installed just fine after signing the apps (wearable and mobile) with release keys, and using adb to install the mobile via usb connection.  Don't know what I was doing wrong with the Eclipse versions.