# Android Wear: Not sync my app to Watch. Why?

Tags: android, wear-os

I has published an android wear app. I installed the app on Google Play and tried to sync with my Androwid Wear via Google Android Wear app but it didn't work.

I guess that the apk I installed doesn't include "WEAR.apk". How can I include it?

When I generated apk on Android Studio, two apks were generated. I uploaded just one apk "APPLICATION.apk". I expected that "APPLICATION.apk" included "WEAR.apk".

build.gradle has the dependency of WEAR.

```
wearApp project(':wear')
```

Does anybody knows any possible reasons and solutions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

[UPDATE1]

・APPLICATION Module

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.hogehoge.bip" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
                android:name="com.hogehoge.bip.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    wearApp project(':Wearable')
    compile files('libs/core-2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javase-2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.5.jar')
}
```

・Wearable Module

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hogehoge.bip" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
                android:name="com.hogehoge.bip.DataLayerListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.hogehoge.bip.PagerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile files('libs/internal_impl-20.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}
```

[UPDATE2]

My app is free. Not paid app.

I generated the followings apks; Application-release.apk(3M) and Wearable-release.apk(1.1M).

[UPDATE3]

I noticed that the similar question had been posted.

[Android Wear generate two apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599852/android-wear-generate-two-apk)

According to the post, I may have to use "release key". I'm checking it.

[UPDATE4]

I uncompressed the apk I publised Google Play. As a result, I found wearable.apk inside handledapp.apk.

I have no idea what should I do next. Can you help me!

[UPDATE5 SOLVED]

I followed the @Gabriele Mariotti's mention. Then it works!

> Check your permissions. The Smartphone part needs to have all the
>   permissions the Wear component has.
>
> Use the same package id for both apps (wear and mobile)

[Android Wear App not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685845/android-wear-app-not-installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a paid app you can't use

```
wearApp project(':wear')
```

you have to [do it manually](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/update-on-android-wear-paid-apps.html)

If it's not a paid app (if it's free), does the file size of the "APPLICATION.apk" correspond to what you would expect? (i.e. wear.apk + mobile.apk)

Also post your manifest and build.gradle files.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My app is free and I attached manifest and build.gradle. I would be grateful you can see it!