# Run Android wear app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-install-apk

I want to create an Android wearable app on Android studio. I have installed the apk file on mobile to test run it. I would like to know how I can run the same apk on wearable device.Also, apk file created on Studio is different for wearable and mobile devices. How can we run it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The APKs are different. When you deploy to Google Play, the wearable APK is embedded inside the mobile APK. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599852/android-wear-generate-two-apk) for more info. If you want to run/test your wearable, you can use the [Android emulators](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html).

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned at [official website](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) you need to create special package signed by **release key**. See more info about packaging [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html).

> When developing, you install apps directly to the wearable like with handheld apps. Use either adb install or the Play button on Android Studio.
>
> > Note: The automatic installation of wearable apps does not work when you are signing apps with a debug key and only works with release keys.

Answer (score 0):

During the development period, do not use release key for signing. Instead, you should build your app which would result in two apks, one for the phone and one for the wear device. Then install each of them separately on the corresponding device using adb or Android Studio. Make sure you are using the same package names for both apks.

When you are done with your development, then build the app with your release key; then the wear apk will be embedded inside your phone apk and installation of your phone apk on a phone will result in the installation of the embedded wear apk on the wear device (make sure you remove the dev apks from both devices prior to this step otherwise installation will fail due to different keys).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to debug through Android Studio as suggested by Julia and Ali, but it is always showing me Parse error while installing or running the code.

I have created a project for both mobile and wear. While running for mobile it works fine in the mobile device but while running the code in the wear it always shows Parse error.

I am using Moto 360 for running and debugging.